# Adding a row with subtotal by category to my dataframe

Tags: pandas, row, subtotal

I have created a new aggregated dataframe by using groupby and I am having problems with adding a subtotal row under each category.

I have tried using pd.groupby and pivottable and changing the index but I don't manage to represent the data as I want it.

- Creates a subtotal of "USD_Balance" for each "Client", but add it as a column:

```
df_balance['Subtotal'] = df_balance.groupby('Client')['USD_Balance'].transform('sum')
```

- Creating a groupby and merging with my raw table gives me the same result.

```
+----------+-------------+------------+
|CLient ID | USD_Balance | Subtotal   |
+----------+---------+------------+----
|       1  |     2       |     6      |      
|       1  |     2       |     6      |     
|       1  |     2       |     6      |    
+----------+-------------+------------+
```

- How I would like to display my data:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Client ID      |    USD_Balance   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        SubTotal     |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I would like to add a Subtotal row, with the corresponding agg per Client ID group.

Thanks in advance for any pointers on how to present my data like this!

Comment: This is with `groupby` I think, so not exactly the same as dup answer. OP just didn't provide more `client ids`. @cs95

Comment: @Erfan Ah that's right. I am sure it is a duplicate of something. Let me know if you find anything. Will reopen for now.

Comment: I have an answer for this, mind if I post it? @cs95

Comment: @Erfan sure and upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `groupby` and access each group and add an *Subtotal* row:

```
dfs = []

for _, d in df.groupby('CLient ID', as_index=False):
    d.loc['Total', 'USD_Balance'] = df['USD_Balance'].sum()
    dfs.append(d)

df_final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
   CLient ID  USD_Balance
0        1.0          2.0
1        1.0          2.0
2        1.0          2.0
3        NaN          6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`sum_res= df.groupby(['CLient ID'],as_index=False)['USD_Balance'].sum()`
`sum_res['grand_total'] ='Grand Total'`
`df.sort_values(by=['CLient ID'],ascending=[True],inplace=True)`
Separate two columns from original dataframe after sorting
`res = df[['CLient ID','USD_Balance']]`
`final_res = pd.concat([res,sum_res])`
`final_res = final_res.sort_values(by=['CLient ID','grand_total'],ascending=[True,True],na_position='first')`
`final_res['CLient ID'] =np.where(final_res['grand_total'].isnull(),
                             final_res['CLient ID'],
                             final_res['grand_total'])`

`final_res.drop(['grand_total'],axis=1,inplace=True)`

Comment: You welcome @CJ123 approve the answer so that more people can benefit from the solution

Answer (score 0):

Are you okay with doing it a little different way?

```
dftotal = df.groupby('CLient ID')['USD_Balance'].sum().reset_index()
dftotal['CLient ID'] = 'SubTotal'
pd.concat([df, dftotal])
```

Output:

```
  CLient ID  USD_Balance
0         1            2
1         1            2
2         1            2
0  SubTotal            6
```